# Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$ be functions. If $f$ onto and $g$ is not onto, then $g \cdot f:A \rightarrow C$ is not onto

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I need help with this proof. I claim it is true, and I want to prove it directly using the definition of onto.

Proof:

Let $A,B,$ and $C$ be sets, and let f, g be functions s.t. $f:A \rightarrow B$ is onto and $g:B \rightarrow C$ is not onto. Then $\forall b \in B, \exists a \in A$ s.t. $f(a) = f(b)$. But since $g: B \rightarrow C$ is not onto...

How do I state that since the range of $g$ is not all of $C$, then there is no way that the domain of $g(f(a))$ can be, either?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There exist $c\in C$ such that $g(b)\neq c,\forall b\in B.$ Now, for any $a\in A$ it is $f(a)\in B.$ Thus, $$(g\circ f)(a)=g(f(a))\ne c, \forall a\in A,$$ which shows that $g\circ f$ is not onto.

(Note that we only need the hypothesis that $g$ is not onto. That is, the result holds independently of $f$ being onto or not.)

Comment: That last bit is a good point, thanks.

Comment: Set theorists employ the notation $ h''S$ (read "h-double-tick  S"). For function $h$ ,define $ h''S=\{h(x) :x\in S\cap (dom (h)\}.$ This is almost always used when $ S\subset dom (h).$  When $S\subset dom (h)$  we have $h''S=\{h(x) :x\in S\}.$ In your Q we have $ f''A\subet B$ and $g''B\ne C,$ By the def'n of $g\cdot  f$ we have  $(g\cdot f)''A=g''(f''A)\subset g''B\ne C.$

Comment: I ran out of  editing time, I meant to say $f''A\subset B$ and $g''B\subsetneq   C.$  So $(g\cdot f)''A=g''(f''A)\subset g''B\subsetneq C.$